# Multiple excel tables to the same sheet?

Tags: c#, excel

Beginner in C# here!  Usually when I build a table (working in VS) I export each table to its own excel sheet.  In the interest of reducing build time and developing my skills, how can I output multiple tables to the same sheet? I know it centers around calling out the default cell, but I can't quite get the syntax right, any help appreciated.

Thanks!

What I have to work with:
just my base build of one table per sheet, something like the following:

## region Product

```
                using (CsvFileWriter writerSupplier = new CsvFileWriter(outputDir + @"\Product.csv"))
                {
                    FulfillmentEntities db = new FulfillmentEntities();
                    db.CommandTimeout = 36000;
                    Worker.ReportProgress(100, "Creating Product Report");
                    Worker.ReportProgress(100, "Setting Product Counts");


                    Worker.ReportProgress(100, "Building Report");

                    CsvRow HeaderRow = new CsvRow();
                    HeaderRow.Add(String.Format("{0}", "A"));
                    HeaderRow.Add(String.Format("{0}", "B")); writerSupplier.WriteRow(HeaderRow);

                   
                    IEnumerable<Field_Master> hits = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Field_Master>
                    (@"INSERT SQL query")

                    foreach (var x in hits)
                    {
                        CsvRow row;

                        row = new CsvRow();
                        row.Add(String.Format("{0}", x.A));
                        row.Add(String.Format("{0}", x.B));                            writerSupplier.WriteRow(row);
                    }
                    writerSupplier.Close();
                    Worker.ReportProgress(100, "Product Report Complete");
                }
                #endregion
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  Exporting data to Excel seems like a tough task for a beginner in C#.

Comment: @DStanley just edited post to include, apologies for any wonky formatting